# Does a sequence of coin flips make dependent sequences more likely to happen? (eg, do 6 successive heads change the probability of tails?)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Sorry if the title is confusing I couldn't think of a snappy way to describe this.

> The raw probability of a getting at least one tails in 15 coin flips is 0.99997 (using the binomial distribution), but I am wondering if there has already been 6 successive heads does this change the probability of tails occurring?

Another way to frame my question is: if you were betting on tails coming up in the next nine coin flips, but you waited until six heads in a row had already appeared are your odds, of a tails appearing in the next nine coin flips, better than if you had simply bet on the first coin flip?

*I don't quite now the proper terminology so I am sure this is confusing, please feel free to ask clarifying questions, and thank you a ton for reading this post*

Comment: The past history does not change the probability of future events, since the flips are independent. What you describe is the Gambler's Fallacy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: Yes, much better. The coin is memoryless and flips are independent so you are now only betting on one tail out of three.

Comment: If you get six heads in a row, you might suspect that there is something wrong with the coin.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not better. In the first scenario, you are looking for the probability that you get at least $1$ tail in the first $9$ flips, which is just $\frac{511}{512}$ cause there is a $\frac{1}{512}$ chance of no tails.

However, in the second situation, if you already know that the first $6$ flips are head, you took the random element away from them, so they aren't included in your probability calculations. Thus, you only focus on the next $9$ flips, and thus there is a $\frac{511}{512}$ chance as calculated before.

Basically, the $9$ flips do not care about what happened before because each flip is independent.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant in both scenarios you are betting one whether there is at least one occurrence of tails in the same amount of runs; so my question is does the fact there are six heads before you choose to bet impact the odds of there being a tails in the next nine rounds? or is it the same odds as if you had bet there will be tails in the next nine rounds, but you are betting with no previous rounds?

Comment: @Arthur Edited, and you may want to add your clarification to your question as well